# How to auto update cart when user delete an item?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, session-variables

I make the cart with a separate page. When view cart button is clicked I load the `php` file of the cart. Where I loop the cart session variable `array` and show in the page. But, when the user press delete button of an item it should be deleted and not shown after in the cart page. Now, how can I automatically update the cart page without reloading the page?

I need some idea how can I implement this?

### loop part

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $result)
                            {
                                ?>
```

delete button

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h6><strong><?php echo $result['price']; ?><span class="text-muted"> x</span></strong></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value=<?php echo $result['quantity']; ?>>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">
           <span class="fa fa-trash"> </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

full source code [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kX9SrwFdhB/)

**Edit 1**
suppose I get the page by `ajax` call

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: 'makeCartPage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(msg)
        {
            //here to code to show the new cart page/information
        },
        error: function()
        {
            console.log('cart error');
        }              
    });
```

But, there was a challenge to show the `ajax` return data.

Comment: idea: to do something without page reloading - you need to use ajax

Comment: @IlyaBursov but how can I show the response data in the correct position.(e.g., quantity)

Comment: next step is to learn about innerHTML property

Comment: You have to set id on top div so when user delete the you have to `document.getElementById().innerHTML = ' ' ` & sever side you have unset that particular result `unset($_SESSION[result])`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this, but one way is to not refresh the list, but rather hide the item you delete, so add a class to the top-level row wrapper class like `product-wrapper` or what-have-you:

```
<div class="row product-wrapper">
```

When you click the `x` button, you run the ajax, update the session on the `makeCartPage.php` page, and on success you traverse the DOM using `$(this)` and hide the `product-wrapper` class. Something like:

```
$('.text-muted').on('click',function(){
    // Isolate the clicked button
    var deleteButton = $(this);
    // Run ajax to remove the item out of the session
    $.ajax({
        url: 'makeCartPage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "id": /* get your product id here however you are able so you can remove from the session */
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // You want to send back a delete success response when you actually 
            // remove it from the session. If true, do something similar to this
            deleteButton.parents('.product-wrapper').fadeOut('fast');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('cart error');
        }
    });
});
```

This should be enough info to get you started. Here is a fiddle of the hiding fx:

https://jsfiddle.net/efL891mu/